# Is there an IQueryBuilder in the .Net Framework?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, interface, dynamics-ax-2009, query-builder

I'm looking to create a query builder to allow me to generate SQL-like queries for Dynamics AX over the Business Connector (BC).  *See below for link/more info on that.

Rather than start from scratch it would be good to reuse an existing interface for this - that way should I ever wish to change from pulling data over the BC to getting data from a database I could easily switch out my builder for a SQLQueryBuilder (or similar) which someone else may have created.

Does anyone know of an existing interface for query builders?

*Dynamics AX Queries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931177(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks Jan - updated - question is does anyone know of an existing interface intended for query builders, so that I can create my own query builder for AX's business connector, but write code such that this could easily be replaced by code to (say) query a database for testing / or to allow me to easily adapt should the data source change in future?